# Will iPhone SE connect to a 802.11b/g router?

Tags: iphone, wifi, router

I plan to purchase iPhone SE. [The spec](https://www.apple.com/lae/iphone-se/specs/) says the Wi-Fi module is 802.11ac (5 GHz band). However, my router is rather old - it [supports](https://www.asus.com/Networking/WL500gP_V2/specifications/) 802.11b and 802.11g only (2.4 GHz band).

I cannot find information on whether a 802.11ac device can work in a backward compatible mode (i.e., on a lower frequency) with a 802.11b/g router or not.

So, will I be able to connect iPhone SE to a 802.11b/g router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

Almost all wifi products are backwards compatible (I can't think of any that aren't). Specifically regarding the iPhone SE, the site [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_se-7969.php) lists the full specs for the iPhone SE's wifi modem: `Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, hotspot`.